# I want to calculate the travel time from one location to another

Tags: android, google-maps

I have already found an answer on StackOverflow to get the distance, but I can't figure out what code to incorporate in this to get the travel time.

```
public String getDistance(final double lat1, final double lon1, final double lat2, final double lon2){
        final String[] parsedDistance = new String[1];
        final String[] response = new String[1];
        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + lat1 + "," + lon1 + "&destination=" + lat2 + "," + lon2 + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving");
                    final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    response[0] = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response[0]);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                    JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
                    JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
                    parsedDistance[0] =distance.getString("text");

                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("HomeMapsActivity", "This is the parsed distance "+parsedDistance);
        return parsedDistance[0];


    }
```

Comment: s/stackoverflow/StackOverflow/

Answer (score 0):

Just like you have fetched the distance object fro the json returned, you have to fetch the duration object.
 JSONObject duration = steps.getJSONObject("duration");

You can also get the duration considering current traffic conditions by passing the traffic_model and departure_time parameters in your url like this -
traffic_model=best_guess&departure_time=now

and then fetch the duration_in_traffic object from the json returned
 JSONObject duration = steps.getJSONObject("duration_in_traffic");

Take a look here - 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TravelModes

Comment: I did just what you said but I am not getting any value for duration!